# creating a new average score for the duplicate records [userid, itemid]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
userid  itemid   score
1       5        4
2       3        10
1       5        20
2       3        30
```

I want to convert this dataframe to:

```
userid  itemid   score
1       5        22
2       3        20
```

I am planning to do this using 2 for loops. However, I wonder if there is any recommended approach for achieving this task? `groupby` does not seem to work since it does not have `average` function. Any help?

Comment: you are looking for [Groupby.mean()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `groupby` and `sum`

```
df.groupby(['userid', 'itemid']).mean()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How will it know to take the mean of `score` column when there are some other columns as well?

Comment: You can tailor this as needed and the more information you provide in your question, the better.  What I provided will find the mean of every column that is numeric.

Comment: I see. May I ask one more question: Why do you think `userid` and `itemid` columns are not included in the result set in my output?

Comment: because that's the default behavior.  If you want those columns back.  do `df.groupby(['userid', 'itemid'], as_index=False).mean()` or `df.groupby(['userid', 'itemid']).mean().reset_index()`

Comment: Thank you my friend, I appreciate it!